# Versioning linux folder with symlinks and them content

Tags: linux, git, versioning, symlink

My use-case is versioning application changes on server because sometimes I need to rollback previous version before update, or before configuration changes.

This is my list of content:

```
dasper@debian:/usr/share/otrs$
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root   4096 Sep 18 16:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 109 root root   4096 Sep 18 13:13 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     21 May  9 11:06 ARCHIVE -> /var/lib/otrs/ARCHIVE
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 Sep 11 15:53 bin
-rwx------   1 root root 212450 Sep 18 16:06 .etckeeper
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   1125 Jan 11  2019 .fetchmailrc.dist
drwx------   8 root root   4096 Sep 18 16:06 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    932 Sep 18 15:40 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root   4096 Sep 11 15:53 Kernel
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    104 Jan 12  2019 RELEASE
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root   4096 Sep 11 15:53 scripts
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      0 Sep 18 15:36 testfile.txt
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     13 May  9 11:06 var -> /var/lib/otrs
```

I was trying [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) to auto commit after package manager make some changes, but git will as defaulte create only empty folder `var/` and `ARCHIVE/`.

I was trying submodules, but then i don't know about changes in symlink folders (`git add .`) and submodule content can't lead to symlink folder.

My biggest issue is how to store these folders in git and how to clone/checkout in same structure.

Comment: If you use `etckeeper` for the custom directory `/usr/share/otrs`, can't you simply use it for `/var/lib/otrs` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was easy & clean, i hope :)

```
apt-get install etckeeper
```

Make directory for repository. This is mounted to other disk

```
mkdir /BACKUP
cd /BACKUP
```

Initialize git repo & set worktree to root /. Now i can tracking whole system changes, not only /etc

```
git init 
git config --path core.worktree /
```

My .gitignore inside /BACKUP:

```
# Ignore everything ~ whitelist
*

# But descend into directories
!*/

# Add /usr/share/otrs/ - main directory
!/usr/share/otrs/**

# Add /var/lib/otrs - symlink # Add /usr/share/otrs/var -> /var/lib/otrs 
!/var/lib/otrs/**

...

# Add myself
!/.gitignore

# Add etckeeper staff
!/etc/.etckeeper/**
```

Add new line at the end of `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` with path to repository:

```
ETCKEEPER_DIR=/BACKUP
```

At the end, remove unused repo initialized by etckeeper after installation:

```
cd /etc
rm -rf .git
rm .gitignore
```

Now you can make first inital commit: `etckeeper commit`